# A buffer-overflow vulnerability in the GNU C Library

Tags: security, vulnerability

I came across this article by PC world informing about some serious vulnerability discovered by Google and Redhat a couple of days before, i am using Ubuntu latest version, and it's up-to-date, do i have to worry, is it been fixed????

Comment: 1. you failed to include a link to the article 2. you failed to include the CVE number so we know what you are talking about.  3. Guessing: http://askubuntu.com/questions/735825/which-ubuntu-releases-have-fixes-for-cve-2015-7547-extremely-severe-bug-with

Comment: i am sorry, here is the link http://www.pcworld.com/article/3033451/linux/use-linux-stop-what-youre-doing-and-apply-this-patch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got the latest updates for Ubuntu yesterday, you should be safe - they released glibc updates (guessing we're talking, indeed, about the latest glibc issues: CVE-2015-7547 and assuming you're using latest/supported versions of ubuntu)

Unless some new bugs have been found meanwhile ;)

cheers

Comment: I am not sure, i m just a regular user, this was the article though http://www.pcworld.com/article/3033451/linux/use-linux-stop-what-youre-doing-and-apply-this-patch.html and yes i am running the latest version of Ubuntu, and its up-to-date.

Comment: I believe you should be fine - keep your system always up to date, and you should be good.